# Canada Pension Plan Transfer

Tags: canada, pension, moving

I have lived for three years in Canada, and made three contributions to the CPP. I now live in Switzerland and do not plan to return to Canada ever.

Is there any way to transfer these contributions into the Swiss system?
The post [Withdraw money from Canada Pension Plan (CPP) or Govt Pension by an Indian Citizen](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/106241/72520)
mentions the possibility of a transfer through a social security agreement between the countries, but other information, I found elsewhere, made it sound that these contributions cannot be transferred.

I am aware, that once I reach the age of retirement I will be able receive benefits from CPP. My Statement of Contributions gives an estimate, but I believe under the assumption that I continue to make contributions. How can I estimate the monthly pension payouts under the assumption that I do not make additional contributions?

Does the Canadian pension system have the property that paying in 2000 CAD/year for 3 years give you roughly 1/10 of the pension you would get when paying in 2000 CAD/year for 30 years?

Comment: Have you tried calling the Canadian Revenue Agnecy? They are usually very helpful and knowledgeable. I'd advise calling them after tax season is over though to avoid long wait times.